# Intellij IDEA give a 'Access can be private' warning for @Bean

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings, access-levels

I am using the latest IntelliJ IDEA free version (2018.1 build july 11.2018).
The code analysis gives me a warning: 'Access can be private' on the method decorated with @Bean.

I searched this problem, but all of answer suggested me to disable this check.

I was wondering is there anyway that I can only disable the check with @Bean rather than totally disabled?

Comment: what is the access level? public? It doesn't give a warning for me (Ultimate v2018.1)

Comment: Could it be that this bean is not used anywhere? And thus it could be private?

Comment: I defined some @Bean public method in spring security config, so the framework will use these bean rather than I use these bean directly. That means if I change these bean to private, I can compile the code, but when I start the spring app, it will give errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition, which does not have this problem. IntelliJ IDEA Community edition does not include the Spring plugin This is why it does not know about the @Bean annotation.

Another solution may be to add the @Bean annotation as Entry Point in the settings for the `Java | Declaration redundancy | Unused declaration` inspection. Then it won't be reported as 'Access can be private'. A disadvantage of this solution is that it also will not be reported as unused, if it isn't used.

Comment: Thanks!   [word patch][word patch][word patch][word patch][word patch]